# Hello world example for spyne SOAP server

Tags: python, soap, suds, spyne

I am experimenting with several different Python SOAP server libraries, and I don't seem to be able to get the 'hello world' example working for [spyne](http://spyne.io/):
https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/helloworld_soap.py

When I run it, it starts up a SOAP server and I can successfully view the WSDL in a browser at `http://localhost:7789/?wsdl`. However, when I try to connect with a suds client, I get an exception:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> c = Client('http://localhost:7789/?wsdl')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/acordiner/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "/home/acordiner/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "/home/acordiner/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.resolve()
  File "/home/acordiner/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 207, in resolve
    c.resolve(self)
  File "/home/acordiner/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 661, in resolve
    self.resolveheaders(definitions, op)
  File "/home/acordiner/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 725, in resolveheaders
    raise Exception, "message'%s', not-found" % mn
Exception: message's0:SomeObject', not-found
```

What could I be doing wrong? I'm using spyne 2.9.4 and suds 0.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry for this confusion.

The example that you linked to is this: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/ec2bd6feb89fb36915b7266497c177e4c6f78b83/examples/helloworld_soap.py

It was used to illustrate a suds bug, which is fixed in [my own version of suds](http://github.com/plq/suds), but not in the mainstream suds. I later forgot to revert it back in the main Spyne repository.

You can find the [relevant commit here](http://github.com/arskom/spyne/commit/a6117cfba7cbab0bd3aa76bd950e8b31b8ebc15c).

Suds can't cope with outgoing header objects whose namespace is different than the `targetNamespace`. You can make your version of suds work by setting `SomeObject.__namespace__ = 'spyne.examples.hello.soap'` instead of `'aaa'`.

You can also just remove the outgoing header declaration which is out-of-place in a helloworld example anyway.

I hope this helps.